# recursive function php + mysql to tree menu

Tags: php, mysql, recursion, hierarchical-data

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP / MySQL build tree menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413776/php-mysql-build-tree-menu)

I need get data between two level build menu.

```
ID | Parent    | Name    | 
 1 | 0         | Cat1    | 
 2 | 1         | SubCat1 | 
 3 | 0         | Cat2    | 
 4 | 3         | SubCat2 | 
 5 | 4         | SubCat3 | 
 6 | 3         | SubCat4 | 
 7 | 3         | SubCat5 |


Level 1: Cat1 and Cat2
Level 2: SubCat1, SubCat2 and Subcat4
Level 3: SubCat3 and SubCat5
```

- Cat1

  - SubCat1
- Cat2

  - SubCat2

    - SubCat3
    - SubCat5
  - SubCat4

I want to level 2 and level 3 menus list data. How I call between 2,3 row?

Answer (score 1):

The correct name here for this data is an **adjacent list hierarchy**

There is a guide on this website to produce this in MySQL

http://kod34fr33.wordpress.com/2008/05/06/adjacency-list-tree-on-mysql/

Comment: thank you, but I can not work with trigger.