# JsTree ul li from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, list, jstree

I'm looking for the simplest way to output an ordered list (UL -> Li ...) from the entries generated by the script server.php provided with JsTree plugin.

[image: Screen Shot of JsTree structure in MySql DB]

Thx for your lights

Comment: Do you want output this by php script to HTML?

Comment: @BattleBit yes. But I mixes my brushes between ULs and LIs :o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be it can help you:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY level;
```

you will receive anything like this:

```
$a = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'parent_id' => 0, 'level' => 0),
    array('id' => 2, 'parent_id' => 1, 'level' => 1),
    array('id' => 3, 'parent_id' => 1, 'level' => 1),
    array('id' => 4, 'parent_id' => 2, 'level' => 2),
    array('id' => 5, 'parent_id' => 3, 'level' => 2)
);
```

Prepare this array:

```
$prepare = array();

foreach ($a as $record) {
    $prepare[$record['id']] = $record;
}
```

And recursive walking it:

```
function getTree($array, $id, $level = 0)
{
    if ($array[$id]['level'] != $level) {
        return;
    }
    echo '<ul>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<li>' . $id;
    foreach ($array as $data) {
        if (($data['parent_id'] === $id)){
            getTree($array, $data['id'], $level + 1);
        }

    }
    echo '</li>'. PHP_EOL;
    echo '</ul>'. PHP_EOL;
}


getTree($prepare, 1);
```

It example do return:

```
<ul>
<li>1<ul>
<li>2<ul>
<li>4</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>3<ul>
<li>5</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have not managed to run your suggestion. But it pointed me to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4414040/1458189) that works perfectly for my needs. Many Thanks for your help.