# How to make tree menu with php

Tags: php, html, sql

I am trying to make a menu tree. My table in my database looks like this:

```
| id        | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| title     | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| parentId  | int(10) unsigned    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| level     | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| sortOrder | int(10) unsigned    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
```

The connection to my database is ok. I have made a loop like this:

```
$test = connexion_DB($db);
$strSQL = "SELECT id, parentId, title, level FROM my_table ORDER BY title ASC";
$sql = requete_SQL($strSQL);
$categories = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $categories[] = array(
      'parentId' => $row['parentId'],
      'level' => $row['level'],
      'title' => $row['title']
    );
}
```

…but I don't know how I can do a tree menu ? Like this:

```
<ul>
<li>Canins
    <ul>
    <li>Chiens</li>
    <li>Loups</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Félins
    <ul>
    <li>Grands Félins
        <ul>
        <li>Lions</li>
        <li>Panthères</li>
        <li>Tigres</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Petits Félins</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Poissons
    <ul>
    <li>Requins</li>
    <li>Saumons</li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Anybody have an idea?

Comment: you should use a recursive function and your mysql should select based on the parentId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search of google found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413776/php-mysql-build-tree-menu). You will need to do a recursive look through your array to get to your final solution.