# dynamic treeview with html,php and javascript and mysql

Tags: php

I have created a table in mysql database using php, and also i can displayed that table on the web form, But the thing is that i want to do, I have six field in my table.

That are,`Sr_no` which is auto increment, `Process_no`, `Process Name`, `Ownership`, `Sheet Revision_no` and `Revision Date`.

Now  i want to make a dynamic tree view type in my field `Process_no`.

For eg: i have the value in that field M01, so when i'll click on M01 then there should be a sub-list under it, such as M01.1, M01.2,.... and so on. and this thing i want in every column of that field.

i had tried a lot but fail to do it.

if you have any solution or any code for it, then please help me.
i'm not a experience candidate, new at php and mysql.

so please help.

Comment: are you storing M01 and M01.1 etc in same column Process_no?

Comment: In the interest of doing your own homework to figure it out you might consider checking out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413776

Comment: nope.... coz my M01 is stored in mysql database so how i can put M01.1 to the same column.