# tree menu php mysql list

Tags: php, mysqli, tree, treeview

I am trying to build an un-oredered list menu tree from my database in PHP and MySQL from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413776/php-mysql-build-tree-menu)

I have an array of page objects I am returning from the db. Each page object has parent_id attribute, which is set to null if it doesn't have a parent. Here's what the page objects look like:

[mydatabase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wW8ah.png)

PHP Handling

```
$menu = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM kategori ORDER BY id_kategori DESC");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($menu)) {
        }   
function has_children($rows,$id) {
  foreach ($rows as $row) {
    if ($row['parent'] == $id)
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
function build_menu($rows,$parent=0)
{  
  $result = "<ul>";
  foreach ($rows as $row)
  {
    if ($row['parent'] == $parent){
      $result.= "<li>{$row['nama_kategori']}";
      if (has_children($rows,$row['id_kategori']))
        $result.= build_menu($rows,$row['id_kategori']);
      $result.= "</li>";
    }
  }
  $result.= "</ul>";

  return $result;
}
echo build_menu($menu);
```

This isn't outputting the correct results for me, can anyone help me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413776/php-mysql-build-tree-menu

Comment: yes, i know that, but i missed query sql, how to replace the array with sql ?

Comment: use mysqli_fetch_array, create menu array first.  provide your sql data base files

Comment: https://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/dynamic-menu-in-php/

Comment: can show me the code ?

Comment: provide your sql data base files with data.

Comment: here is sol.     while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($menu)) {
        $data[] = $row;

        }    echo build_menu($data);

Comment: This isn't outputting the correct results for me. I was updated it, but that shouldn't have changed anything, look at mydatabase above? please

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FT86S5G79C33

Comment: sorry, its correct thanks dude

Comment: https://prnt.sc/k5iipq