# php mysql category subcategory list link

Tags: php, mysql

I want to like this

Category1

--Subcat1

--Subcat2

Category2

--Subcat2

I have two tables tbl_cat and tbl_subcat

tbl_cat(id,cat_name)

tbl_subcat(id,**cat_id**,subcat_name)

> cat_id=tbl_cat.id

how to I write the function and display the category and sub-category link

Comment: Hope help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413776/php-mysql-build-tree-menu

Comment: Hello, Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please edit your question so that it is clearly stated in the title.
also start your post with your question and try to make people understand what you're asking must of us don't have context on what is going on in your project.

Comment: Kindly refer to this [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this.

Test data:

```
create table tbl_cat (id int, cat_name varchar(32));
insert into tbl_cat(id, cat_name) values(1, "category1"), (2, "category2");
create table tbl_subcat (id int, cat_id int, subcat_name varchar(32));
insert into tbl_subcat(id, cat_id, subcat_name) values(1, 1, "subcat11"), (2, 1, "subcat12"), (3, 1, "subcat13"), (4, 2, "subcat21");
```

Then, PHP script can be written like this:

```
<?php 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "your_user";
$password = "your_password";
$dbname = "test";


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT cat_name, subcat_name FROM tbl_cat LEFT JOIN tbl_subcat ON tbl_cat.id = tbl_subcat.cat_id;";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$last_category = "";
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $cat_name = $row["cat_name"];
        if ($cat_name != $last_category) {
            echo "Category: " . $cat_name .PHP_EOL;
            $last_category = $cat_name;
        }
        echo "\tSubcategory: " . $row["subcat_name"] .PHP_EOL;
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```